# Hosting service physical distance from the user

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

Is there a downside of using hoisting provider that's on the other side of the planet relative to the user base? 
My user base is mostly from USA. 
What happens if I host my site in New Zealand rather than USA? Will my users experience increased lag or delay?

To clarify why I'm moving out of USA - I live in EU and I can't store private info in USA without permission from EU according to data protection directive and it seems that getting this permission is a pain. I'm not even gonna bother trying. New Zealand however is regarded as safe by EU standards (for whatever crazy reason) so I was thinking about going there until something changes in EU.

Answer (score 1):

1]Certainly there will be time lag if your website is hosted in New Zealand instead of USA when majority of your customer is based in USA.

2]You may test time lag by PING statistics of Data center located in USA and New Zealand. You may search hosing provider(Data center) on line for USA/New Zealand, ask IP to their Support Technician by live chat and test PING statistics before you finalize your hosting provider.